# How to connect corners detected by Harris to build a graph

Tags: python, opencv, graph-theory, canny-operator

I have used Harris Corner Detection algorithm to find the corners in an image. Now, I want to connect specific corners straightly to build a graph.
I also have used Canny Edge Detection, and the corners should be connected together based on the paths defined by the edges.
Any idea how should I connect these corners?

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).